# What could be reasons for this android EditText control to convert the input to the ascii sequence

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So for some project i'm working with Xamarin.Forms.

Since one area is just unbearably slow with Xamarin.Forms i've used a CustomRenderer to solve one particular area where a list is involved.

After getting back to the project and upgrading packages, i've suddenly got the weirdest bug.

I am setting `"1234"` to an `EditText`, and the `EditText.Text` Property is suddenly `"49505152"` - the string is converted to its ascii equivalent.

[image: value]
[image: assignment result]

Is this a known issue? Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I think it is fairly impossible to say anything useful about this without seeing the actual code that is implemented in the custom renderer. Please add it to your question.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis That's ok. This was the kind of code which i had to debug myself to find the answer, because it is something uncommon

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue was that my `EditText` had an `InputFilter` applied and that after updating a package suddenly another code path of `FilterFormatted` was executed.

```
    public ICharSequence FilterFormatted(ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        var startSection = dest.SubSequenceFormatted(0, dstart);
        var insert = source.SubSequenceFormatted(start, end);
        var endSection = dest.SubSequenceFormatted(dstart, dest.Length());
        var merged = $"{startSection}{insert}{endSection}";
        if (ValidationRegex.IsMatch(merged) && InputRangeCheck(merged, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                char c = source.CharAt(i);
                sb.Append(c);
            }

            if (source is ISpanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                TextUtils.CopySpansFrom((ISpanned)source, start, sb.Length(), null, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                // AFTER UPDATE THIS PATH WAS ENTERED UNLIKE BEFORE
                return sb;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new SpannableString(string.Empty);
        }
    }
```